# Getting all post data even when specifying post id to get just one - WPGraphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, wp-graphql

I am trying to get a cursor for a post given the postId but in return I am getting cursors of all posts. Note that this query works fine when I hardcode the id into the query.

query:

```
export const GET_POST_CURSOR = gql `
  query GetPostById($id: Int) {
    posts(where: {id: $id}) {
      edges {
        cursor
      }
      
    }
  }
`;
```

React

```
let postId = 138
const postCursor = useQuery(GET_POST_CURSOR, {variables: {postId}}) 
  
  if (!postCursor.loading) { 
    console.log("cursor: ", postCursor)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React

```js
let postId = 138;
const postCursor = useQuery(GET_POST_CURSOR, {variables: {id: postId}})
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: the gql filter data by `id`. set the variables like this `{variables: {postId}}` means the gql receives `postId` not `id`, you need to change to `{variables: {id: postId}}`